# Analytic continuation / equivalence based on both value and complex derivate at 2 isolated points.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

This is is a question which will help me ensure I have understood complex analysis and analytic continuation.

We start with an analytic function $f(z)$, holomorphic in the entire complex plane for simplicity.

If we then have a candidate analytic function $g(z)$ which agrees with $f(z)$ at two isolated points $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Question 1: Agreement between $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ at $z_1$ and $z_2$ is insufficient to say they are equivalent, or one is an analytic continuation of the other. Is this correct?

I know (I think) that if there is agreement at every point along a path between $z_1$ and $z_2$, that is sufficient.

Question 2: If there is agreement between $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ at $z_1$ and $z_2$ regarding both their values, **and also their complex derivates at those points**, then this is sufficient. Is this correct?

Comment: Are the functions $f(z)=z^2(z-1)^2(z-2)$ and $g(z)=z^2(z-1)^3$ the same function just because they and their derivatives both agree at $z_1=0$ and $z_2=1$?

Comment: you need complex derivatives of all orders equal at a point ($f^{(n)}(a)=g^{(n)}(a), n \ge 0$ for some $a$ then $f=g$; there are some subtler conditions about sets of values (something like the set of $f(x)=a$ and $g(x)=a$ coincide including multiplicities for five such $a$ then $f=g$  this one allows $f,g$ meromorphic so for entire functions four values are enough as the sets $f(x)=g(x)=\infty$ are equal being empty)

Comment: hi @Conrad - helpful input as always, thanks. If an analytic function has a derivative, then by definition it has derivatives of infinite order - so we shouldn't need to require "smoothness" in addition to analyticity? Also I need to find out more about the "sets of points" because this is the first time I've read about the sufficiency of 4 and 5 points. I had thought we needed points such that the radius of convergence of their Taylor series didn't leave any point left out - which could be fulfilled by 2 points?